# How to set Paragraph Attributes for a Row / Cell in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I can insert a table in a Google Document. I manage to change some of the Attributes of each row (like font size, bold, padding).

However, paragraph Attributes I get stuck at. Like LINE_SPACING, SPACING_AFTER, SPACING_BEFORE.

How do I set the Attributes of a table row and table cells?

And while I'm at it :-), how to put a bullet list in a cell?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

==== update  ====

Found the answer

```
tabel.getRow(0).getCell(1).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes(something)
```